# Firebase DB imports JSON data in alphabet order

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when I import JSON data into firebase using import option on the GUI, the data is loaded into firebase in alphabet order. But I need data to be loaded in the order I have in JSON. Does anyone know a way to load JSON data into firebase DB in the order the data in JSON file.

Comment: Hey! If you take a look at the firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data you can `orderByChild` `orderByKey` or `orderByValue` if this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console always shows children in that order.  That's just how the console works.

If you need ordering in your app, your query should indicate the order of results using [one of the ordering methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order).

Comment: i imported json message using import option on the firebase console. the console shows in alphabet order. when i try to retrieve using programming language it returns in alphabet order.

Comment: If your query isn't working, then you should explain what you're trying to do, show your data structure, show your query, and say what's not working the way you expect.  This is a lot more than the question you originally asked.

Comment: thank you. here is my data structure.{
  "Category" : {
    "-L2ok7P8Mh_r6bN2blnT" : {
      "companyName" : "A1",
   "status" : "available",
   "addressLine1" : " drive",
      "addressLine2" : "path",
       "town" : "yale",
   "county": "mycounty",
   "postcode" : "yu787282",
         "country" : "mycountry",
      "contact_mobile" : 780121212,
      "contact_work_number" : 1189121212,
    }
 }
 }

Comment: when I import this json data into firebase console, it inserts in alphabet order.

Comment: so I wonder why firebase console import options stores data in alphabet order. what I need to add in JSON message to store data in firestore in the order I have. thanks.

Comment: I think you're not understanding. There is no implied order to children. The console just shows them that way, because that's just how it works. Don't take the console order to mean anything. You should only impose ordering in your own app.